# Contains object in map of maps

Tags: java

I have a map of maps and I need to see if an object is in a value of a map.

Previously, the code looked like this:

```
objectMap = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();

protected boolean containsObject(final byte[] testObject) {
for(byte[] bytes : objectMap.values()) {
  if (Arrays.equals(bytes, testObject)) {
    return true;
  }
}
return false;
}
```

This worked fine.  However, the `objectMap` has now changed to:

```
objectMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, byte[]>>();
```

Now I need to have the same containsObject method ...

```
protected boolean containsObject(final byte[] testObject) {
for(Map<String, byte[]> map : objectMap.values()) {
  if (value of map.equals(testObject)) {
    return true;
  }
}
return false;
}
```

What I'm not sure on is how to get the value of the map that's being iterated since I don't have a key to work with.

Thanks.

Comment: The key is the String, isn't it?

Comment: you try to compare byte array (testObject) and a Map. I really can not get what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't actually have access to that I don't think

Comment: @erencan I need to do the same thing as the first example code but now with the Map inside of the Map.  It's a hard problem to put into words...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the `values` of the `values`.  You already called `values()` to get the `byte[]` from the first example.  Now you're getting another `Map`, from which you can call `values()` again.

```
for (Map<String, byte[]> map : objectMap.values()) {
    for (byte[] bytes: map.values()) {
        // Test for equality as you already have done before.
```

Comment: I was thinking of that as well but wasn't sure if that's the best/only way to do it.  No reason that wouldn't work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your testing is a map is equal to a byte[]. This can never be logically true.

You'll want to loop through the map's values and check each one:

```
protected boolean containsObject(final byte[] testObject) {
   for(Map<String, byte[]> map : objectMap.values()) {
       for(byte[] b : map.values()) {
            if (Arrays.equals(b,testObject)) {
               return true;
            }
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the answer above also mentions the same thing.  I know I was comparing a map to a byte[], but I wasn't sure if a double for loop was the best way to go about checking the values or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try using the [keySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29)-Method of your outer map. Like this:

```
protected boolean containsObject(final byte[] testObject) {
  for(Map<String, byte[]> map : objectMap.values()) {
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
      if(map.get(key).equals(testObject) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acces it using Map.Entry, here is an exemple :

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : objectMap ) {  
  System.out.println(" Key: " + entry.getKey());  
  System.out.println(" Value: " + entry.getValue());  
  entry.setValue("Khanjian");  
}
```